# URLConnection seems to die early Java

Tags: java, http

Here is the code I'm using

```
    URLConnection connection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    Scanner scanner = null;

    try {
        connection = new URL("http://www.aol.com").openConnection();
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);

    System.out.println(connection.getReadTimeout());

    while(scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
```

it's seems the timeout is set to 0, but it always dies at the same spot depending on where I execute this code. But each location always stops reading at the same spot.  I ran a debugger and after it dies, scanner.next() doesn't return. I know it's not part of the input because different locations of this code stop at different times. I'm assuming it has to do with the run time.

Please help :-(

Answer (score 0):

I ran your (slightly simplified) code and got the whole HTML page back.

```
final URLConnection connection = new URL("http://www.aol.com").openConnection();
System.out.println(connection.getReadTimeout());
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
scanner.close();
```

Output:

```
0
<html
   ... many tons of html ...
</html>
```

Comment: what version of Java are u using

Comment: It could be a bug with se 7, I'm using se 7

Comment: The chance that it is a bug with JSE is really low indeed. I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: I tested the exact code on my other computer which also is a mac running 6, and it did run fine as well. I'm not sure what it can be other than the se 7 library if it runs on 6 fine, and the api hasn't changed

Comment: I retested it with 6 on my win pc and it also works, so there is likely something wrong with 7, as strange as that sounds

Answer (score 0):

There nothing wrong with your code here. You should check your network connection. Your proxy may be very unresponse. Try using:

```
new URL("http://www.aol.com").openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider directly accessing HTTP data from standard Java SE classes to be low level. The [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) library will deal with a lot of the nuances - which usually show themselves in code like your question. If you're encountering configuration problems, this might actually transparently deal with them. Give it a try to see if it helps:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(5000);
HttpMethod method = new GetMethod("http://www.aol.com");
method.setFollowRedirects(true);
client.executeMethod(method);
String responseBody = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
method.releaseConnection();
```

Otherwise, the other solutions might help you narrow down the exact problem with your configuration, because your code looks fine.

Comment: It *isn't* '@Deprecated', and it should also work. Not an answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect why it would be a good idea to try a higher level library. The questioner is obviously suffering from a config or networking problem, the code looks fine.

Comment: Exactly, so why would changing libraries help at all? Not an answer.